# Get total cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I need to have the import of **cart** in **woocommerce**.
But i need the number without **wc_price().**
This is my code:

```
global $woocommerce;
$app=$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
$app2=$woocommerce->cart->total;
```

and it results:

```
app = $20.00
app2 = 0
```

and the cart is of $20.00
Thanks.

Comment: So... what is your issue exactly?

Comment: my cart is of $20.00 and i need to have variable $app=20.00

Comment: Maybe it helps someone... Please try `$app2 = WC()->cart->total;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try

```
$app= (float) preg_replace( '/[^0-9\.]/', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total()  );
```

Or

```
$app = str_replace('$','',$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() );
```

the solution depends on the type of currency that is occupied in this case the euro occupied, so we had to replace the euro in htmlentities as shown here

```
str_replace ( '& euro;', '', $ woocommerce-> cart-> get_cart_total ());
```

**Note:** trim '& euro'

Comment: the result is $app=2000

Comment: try change `$app= preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/','',$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() );`  @SafuanDinar

Comment: I test  example : `$number =  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
$app=  preg_replace( '/[^0-9\.]/', '', $number ) ;
echo (float) $number;` and show 20 this ok,  php clean zero at right, for example your get_cart_total number was $20.100 this out $20.1 try and comment @SafuanDinar

Comment: i have tried your last code, but it give me always 2000:   `number = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
 $app= preg_replace( '/[^0-9\.]/', '', $number ) ; 
    wc_add_notice( __( 'cont '.$cont.' number= '.(float) $number.'val='. (float) $app.'', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );`   @guillermoAndresFuentesMoral

Comment: You try `$number = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); $app= str_replace( '$', '', $number ) ; wc_add_notice( __( 'cont '.$cont.' number= '. $number.'val='.  $app.'', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );`
 I edit the answer @SafuanDinar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104892/discussion-between-safuan-dinar-and-guillermo-andres-fuentes-moral).

Comment: Yes now i have 20,00 but if i want make 20,00-10 it give me -10.

Comment: You need clean span  `$app = strip_tags(str_replace('$','',$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ));` and convert in float

Comment: to convert in float: ` $app= (float) $app2;`

Comment: `$app= (float) $app2;` becasuse $app2?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
global $woocommerce;
$Cart = WC()->cart->subtotal;
echo "CART : " . $Cart;
```